# Run Expo EAS build release tar.gz file rather than apk file

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I follow this example to build project by command:

`eas build -p android --profile preview`

also tried

`eas build --profile production --platform android`

in this document
https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/apk/#configuring-a-profile-to-build-apks

and my eas.json is

```
{
    "build": {
        "preview": {
            "android": {
                "buildType": "apk"
            }
        },
        "preview2": {
            "android": {
                "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
            }
        },
        "preview3": {
            "developmentClient": true
        },
        "production": {
            "android": {
                "buildType": "apk"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I got  tar.gz rather than .apk file link.

I don't know where is the problem for.

(I can build apk yesterday and I just add firebase in project today)

Thank you.

Comment: I found another way install in android phone, Should to convert file to apk by online service(or other), then put it on cloud, use link to download too.(not a good solution)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to specify the `applicationArchivePath`. By default, an *.apk and *.aab-file are assembled (and therefor packed in a tarball). You can narrow it down by specifying the output.

```
"build": {
    "preview": {
        "android": {
            "buildType": "apk",
            "applicationArchivePath": "android/app/build/outputs/**/*.apk"
        }
    },
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer me. But I still got .tar.gz file link when I edit my eas.json like yours. I don't know why :(